# Proving characteristic properties

Tags: statistics

How to prove that the second order characteristic function MUV(wU,wV) with wV=0 is equal to the characteristic function MU(w) of the random variable U alone?

How to prove that for 2 independent random variables U and V, Muv(wU,wV)=MU(wU)MV(wV)?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I’ve tried going through the book , and have proved every characteristic function has a value of 1 , but am unsure how to approach these 2 problems. I end up in a loop of pretty much saying “this is this “